# Is asking for a natural explanation for a supernatural event allowed on this site?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

The birth of Vyāsa's son, Śuka, is [narrated](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c024.htm) in the Mahābhārata as follows:

> Bhishma said. 'The son of Satyavati having obtained this high boon from the great God, was one day employed in rubbing his sticks for making a fire. While thus engaged, the illustrious Rishi, O king, beheld the Apsara Ghritachi, who, in consequence of her energy, was then possessed of great beauty. Beholding the Apsara in those woods, the illustrious Rishi Vyasa, O Yudhishthira, became suddenly smitten with desire. The Apsara (Ghritachi), seeing the Rishi's heart troubled by desire, transformed herself into a she-parrot and came to that spot. Although he beheld the Apsara disguised in another form, the desire that had arisen in the Rishi's heart (without disappearing) spread itself over every part of his body. Summoning all his patience, the ascetic endeavoured to suppress that desire; with all his effort, however, Vyasa did not succeed in controlling his agitated mind. In consequence of the inevitability of what was to happen, the Rishi's heart was attracted by Ghritachi's fair form. He set himself more earnestly to the task of making a fire for suppressing his emotion, but in spite of all his efforts his vital seed came out. That best of regenerate ones, however, O king, continued to rub his stick without feeling any scruples for what had happened. **From the seed that fell, was born a son unto him, called Suka.** In consequence of his circumstance attending his birth, he came to be called by name of Suka.

Now if some Hindus believe babies cannot be born without copulation or without a mother bearing the child for 9 months, can they ask the following question, based on the above story, on this site?

> I do not believe the entire official story to be true, as it's impossible for a human to be born out of thin air. So who's the real biological (human) mother of Śuka? Who was the lady that delivered and raised him? Was it Ghṛtācī? If yes, what was her varṇa/caste? Also, if she's a human after all, what does "she-parrot" in the story signify?

Are questions of this sort allowed? If not, why not?

I understand the speculative nature of such questions, but if we have to determine the birth-based varṇa/caste of Śuka it is especially important that we know who his human mother was. Don't we?

---

EDIT

Here's my attempt to post the specific example I cited above on the main site:

[What is Śuka's birth-based varṇa? Is his biological mother literally a parrot or a human named Ghṛtācī or he had no mother at all?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22975)

Comment: What you have to do is ask it in a way that doesn't provoke speculation.  You could ask "Do any scriptures mention a human mother for Shuka?" or "Has anyone argued that Shuka had a human mother, and if so who do they argue it was?"  Something of that kind, a factual question that has a factual answer.

Comment: 'Has _anyone_ argued that Shuka had a human mother' - can a user provide an original argument in the answer without any references? Is that valid?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be valid.  This isn't a discussion site, this is a Q&A site where people can ask and answer factual questions about Hinduism.  We're here to create a knowledge base, documenting what is already known about Hinduism, not breaking new ground.  (There's nothing wrong with breaking new ground, but this is not the venue for it.)

Comment: 'not breaking new ground...this is not the venue for it' - Why should this site care about it? How is it different from users trying to provide custom/creative interpretation of Bhagavad Gita verses in their answers? Also, there are more and more English translations of BG coming up all the time. If some users choose to cite those new versions of BG, are they 'breaking new ground'?

Comment: If a question asked "Adi Shankaracharya says this is the right interpretation of this Gita verse, Ramanujacharya says that is the right interpretation of this Gita verse, what is the right interpretation of this Gita verse", that should absolutely be closed.  Again, this is not a discussion site.

Comment: I agree the main site is not meant for discussion which is why I posted this question on meta first to see what other users think about such questions. But no matter how you ask questions that try to solve the mystery surrounding miraculous human births it will be closed down as subjective/speculative.

Comment: Again, there are valid ways to ask it, ways that do not solicit speculation.  Like asking for solutions others have already come up with.  But trying to solve it yourself is not what this site is for.